# Reading from NegotiatedContentResult object (sent from WebAPI) in angular js promise

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api

Displayed below is my WebAPI method which returns a list of Information about several books.

```
   [System.Web.Http.Authorize]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _assetAssetRepository.View(id);
            if (result == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
             return Content(HttpStatusCode.Found, result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                "Exception Occurred" + ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }
```

Angular js code to consume this data

```
    var getAssetDetails = function (assetId) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get("/api/Asset/" + assetId, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $cookies.get('accessToken') } })
         .then(function (response) {
             deferred.resolve(response);
         }).catch(function (response) {
             alert("Oops something wrong: " + response.data);
             deferred.reject(response);
         }).finally(function () {

         });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

The bit i am struggling is if you replace this line of code in webapi 
  "return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK,result)" with "return Ok(result)" i can see the data in the UI without any problem. However when i use 
 "return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK,result)",  the angular code for some cannot read this and throws out exception and shows the alert message saying "Oops something wrong [object Object]" so it seems like its getting the data but for some reason its still throwing exception. Anyone up for help?

Comment: Inside your `catch` callback you receive an exception as parameter, and not the http response. Please analyze this exception so we can help you better.

Comment: Try `response.responseText` or `response.responseJSON`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's best to start with details given by the catch block. But one of many errors can be (which I first had):

> Unexpected token R in JSON at position 0

which is be due to `responseType: 'JSON'` added in your http request. Angular takes the response as JSON where in this case it is not. So we need to remove this.

Here is how I do it (end-to-end). From my API:

```
 return Content(HttpStatusCode.<statuscode>, "ResponseContent: " + "my_custom_error");
```

Second Case:

```
//If I'm getting output from another API/Layer then I pass it's output like this
var output = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
return Content(response.StatusCode, "ResponseContent: " + output);
```

And in the Angular code, I read it like this:

```
$http({ method: methodType, url: endpoint })
     .then(function (response) {
          response.status; //gets you the HttpStatusCode to play with
          response.data; //gets you the ReponseContent section
     }, function (response) {
          response.status; //gets you the HttpStatusCode
          response.data; //gets you the ReponseContent section
     });
```

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

The response object has these properties:

> data    – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the
>   transform functions.
>
> status  – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
>
> headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
>
> config  – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to
>   generate the request.
>
> statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.